# Nandroid Backup restore fails with error 255

Tags: twrp, nandroid

I recently destroyed the screen of my OnePlus One and had to send it in for repair. I used TWRP to make a Nandroid Backup before packing the device.
Yesterday, I received a new device, obviously not having my apps and data. So I moved my backup onto the device, but when I try to restore it, I get errors.

When restoring the data partition, it will get to 79% and then say

```
E:extractTarFork() process ended with ERROR=255.
```

I tried it multiple times with the same result. Unfortunately, I obviously cannot try creating a new backup. All other partitions restore without trouble.

According to the log files, the file causing the issue is
`//data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.instabridge.android-2@base.apk@classes.dex`.

What can I do? I thought it might help to delete the file as the Dalvik Cache is just a cache that will be recreated, but how do I delete files or folders from a Nandroid Backup?

Comment: See if [Nandroid Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h3r3t1c.bkrestore&hl=en) helps.

Comment: Did that already. It can extract but not delete files.

Comment: The `.win` files created by TWRP are really just tar archives or system images and can be manipulated as such using relevant tools for those file formats.  Note that if you have hash checking on, modifications will break the hash (either recompute md5 or disable hash checking)

Comment: Specifically, you could use the `tar` command to untar/tar files (of course skipping the files you don't want when retarring).  Similarly, you could mount a system image using a loop device.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, turns out I did not have enough space on the phone.

So backup_file_size * 2 < memory_availaible

The data partition is mostly big so it might be exceeding the capacity.

A good alternative might be restoring from a USB device or an SD card.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to delete the file or folder from Nandroid backup. Just delete the file which is causing the issue, change into that directory, and use the `rm` command to remove the file.

**In your case:**

```
> cd /data/dalvik-cache/arm

> rm -f data@app@com.instabridge.android-2@base.apk@classes.dex
```

Then, without rebooting, do a backup or restore as you need!

Answer (score 0):

> When restoring the data partition, it will get to 79% and then say
> `E:extractTarFork() process ended with ERROR=255`. I tried it multiple times with the same result. Unfortunately, I obviously cannot try creating a new backup. All other partitions restore without trouble.

I think the easiest solution to this problem if it falls on the data. Try wiping Dalvik and cache, then formatting memory after restore backup from SD card. If you have the TWRP backup in your internal phone memory, move it to your external memory card so you don't lose it.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it's not a corrupt file or anything. It's just your disk filled with your backup so badly that it can't restore your files.